# How to install ssmtp on mac?

Tags: homebrew

I want to install the ssmtp (http://archive09.linux.com/feature/132006) on my Mac (El Capitan).

I have homebrew installed but ssmtp isn't one of the packages available.

What are my options for getting ssmtp installed? I'm guessing the only way is to compile it from source code but I'm not sure where to get the source code and what commands to run.

Comment: As a note for other readers macports does have a ssmtp port. Sorry no use for the OP as you can't mix package managers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the only option is to compile the source code.

You can download from the [project repository on github](https://github.com/ajwans/sSMTP). There is a [download button there](https://github.com/ajwans/sSMTP/archive/master.zip).

To install it, your have to uncompress the downloaded file. Once done, cd to sSMTP-master directory.

The generic compilation process is executing the following commands one by one:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

The `configure` command can be altered with lots of parameters. To let you know your options, you can run `./configure --help`

Comment: Look at the simp page the configure *will* require more options and also I think you need others to find the Homebrew libraries

Comment: @Mark No, it doesn't require any extra option to compile, make and install. Tested.

Comment: I saw the ` --enable-ssl --enable-md5auth` in the linux.com page

Comment: @Mark is an option, but it's not required. You can or cannot enable, is up to you.

Comment: --enable-ssl --enable-md5auth works if your choose to use gnussl. The command will be ./configure --enable-ssl--with-gnutls --enable-md5auth

Comment: Unfortunately after a successful build, it crashes when I run it: `[1]    71623 segmentation fault  ./ssmtp`